# Best WordPress Cloud Hosting Provider that allows installation of ffmpeg 4.0

Tags: server

I all. I have a couple of wordpress sites hosted with cloudways. I've generally enjoyed the service for the last 5 years with only a few hiccups, more so when i first started using them. Sites run lightning fast, my social network however, built on wordpress needed lots and lots of attention and at one stage open heart surgery. But generally everything is fine. Cloudways used to offer autoscalling based on usage, but then stopped this about a year ago. Another real bug bear I have is that ffmpeg is only available upto 2.0 on all server, no matter which provider you choose. Here;s the issue, I already pay about $100 a month for two digital cloud servers. Cloudways now said that the only way for me to be able to use ffmpeg 4.0 (the standard now) is to upgrade my account and pay them an extra extra $100 a month in order for them to install ffmpeg 4.0 in my server. Yes you heard that correctly!!! not so cheap now. I really need ffmpeg 4.0 operating in one of my servers, and I am certainly not going to spend an extra $100 a month to get it. After all the hard work put into settting up my server, and sites, I now learn that cloudways isnt as cheap as some people may think. Any suggestions out there? DO i bite the bullet and more again, is there another way, so plugin maybe that can achieve the same without cloudways knowing, if I access ssh the system will not let me install the package myself. any advice? or if not where to next?

See full conversation below
————————

Zeeshan Kareem
Cloud Engineer

Zeeshan Kareem 20:58
Hello! Welcome to Cloudways! Please let us know how may I help you today?
21:01
what happened to Kyup

https://community.cloudways.com/t/introducing-autoscaling-container-hosting-by-cloudways-kyup/55

I wanted to test it out
Zeeshan Kareem 21:03
Dean, I am sorry curently we don't provide KYUP server, Currently we provide only 5 provider

In order to select the upstream provider you can follow this link.
https://support.cloudways.com/which-infrastructure-provider-do-i-have-to-choose/
20:59
I already have two servers with you. But i was interested in the ability to up and down scale automatically

with demand

and with no downtime

siteground offer this capability: https://www.siteground.co.uk/cloud-hosting.htm

they are cheaper to start with but overall are more expansive in the long run

depending on how big a site gets
Zeeshan Kareem 21:07
I am sorry curently we don't provide auto scaling facility. You can suggest new features or other service improvements in our feedback page: http://feedback.cloudways.com/
21:07
ok so I guess its something you did do, but then cancelled?

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/deploy-web-apps-on-kyup-cloud/
Zeeshan Kareem 21:08
yes in the past, we provide KYUP server currently we don't provide KYUP
21:08
ok, you need to update your blogs
Zeeshan Kareem 21:09
Thank you for highlighting I have forwarded this to my team
21:10
just one more question, i maybe forced to move one of my servers to siteground just becuase you are unable to provide the updated ffmpeg 4.0. and the only way for me to get that is to upgrade and pay you guys an extra $100 in support fees a month. I just want to clarify that I have got this right for the record?

is this correct?
Read
Zeeshan Kareem 21:13
Let me confirm

So yes or no? do I need to pay an extra $100 a month to be able to use the upgraded FFmpeg 4.0?
Zeeshan Kareem 21:21
Dean, for the customization on the server you need to take the advance support
Dean Jones 21:15
which is $100 extra a month?
Read
Zeeshan Kareem 21:21
Yes
Dean Jones 21:15
thanks for confirming

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Siteground](https://www.siteground.com/). It offers free FFmpeg support on all hosting solutions. [FastComet](https://www.fastcomet.com/) also offers free FFmpeg support. You can find their detailed comparison [right here](https://hostadvice.com/tools/web-hosting-comparison/fastcomet-vs-siteground/).